# Accessing JSON data with colon in the label

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have json data with a colon in the label (see responsedata) which I'm finding difficult to access in Angular with the following code:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items.autnresponse.responsedata | searchFor:searchString"> <p>{{i.autn:numhits}}</p> </li>
```

I keep getting an error like this:

`Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [i.autn:numhits] starting at [:numhits]`.

JSON data excerpt:

```
"autnresponse": {
    "action": {
        "$": "QUERY"
    },
    "response": {
        "$": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "responsedata": {
        "autn:numhits": {
        "$": "92"
    },
    "autn:totalhits": {
        "$": "92"
    },
    "autn:totaldbdocs": {
        "$": "188"
    },
    "autn:totaldbsecs": {
        "$": "188"
    },
```

Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: Which language are you trying to access it with? JavaScript? Perl? Python? Something else?

Comment: apologies, trying to access it with angularjs

Comment: Is it failing to parse from JSON into JS structure, or is a line of code you wrote having trouble accessing something in the resulting JS structures? If the latter, please provide the line of code.

Comment: it works fine for the labels that have no colon in the label but when I try something like {{i.autn:numhits}} i get the error... it doesn't like the colon in the json label

Comment: <li ng-repeat="i in items.autnresponse.responsedata | searchFor:searchString">
            
            <p>{{i.autn:numhits}}</p>
           
        </li>

Comment: Yes, look at JAAulde's answer. You need the square brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume I know the answer to my question from the comments and post what would be my response:

**Assumption**

Your JSON parses fine but your code can't access something in the resulting data structure

**Answer**

Use square bracket notation with a string:

```
var x = i['autn:numhits'];
```

The same can be used when you have a property name in a variable.  Using your same example:

```
var propertyName = 'autn:numhits';
var x = i[propertyName];
```

**Addendum**

For Angular template, try

```
{{i['autn:numhits']}}
```

Comment: Thx :) This might've taken me hours to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets to access it like a dictionary rather than dot notation. Replace `{{i.autn:numhits}}` with `{{i['autn:numhits']}}`

As a heads up, if you want to wrap autn:numhits with double quotes you will need to html escape them.

Comment: thnx for the explanation, makes more sense now